# R: Cut time-series of measurements by a column of start and end dates

Tags: r

I have a time-series of CO2 measurements in one data.frame and another data.frame that includes a columns of dates representing (startExperiment, stopExperiment). I would like to cut the CO2 data into segments that fit between startExperiment and stopExperiment. I think I'm close but not quite there.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Sensor Dev.Date.Time       Date       CO2.ppm. Temp  RH   
  <fctr> <dttm>              <date>        <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 A1     2019-02-07 12:01:49 2019-02-07      607 22.7  44   
2 A1     2019-02-07 12:01:59 2019-02-07      602 22.7  44   
3 A1     2019-02-07 12:02:09 2019-02-07      600 22.7  44   
4 A1     2019-02-07 12:02:19 2019-02-07      597 22.8  45   
5 A1     2019-02-07 12:02:29 2019-02-07      594 22.8  45   
6 A1     2019-02-07 12:02:39 2019-02-07      594 22.8  45
```

exptList

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  value                                  
  <chr>                                  
1 2019-02-07 09:00:00 2019-02-07 17:00:00
2 2019-02-11 11:33:00 2019-02-11 13:25:00
3 2019-02-12 13:25:00 2019-02-12 14:00:00
4 2019-02-18 12:12:00 2019-02-18 12:53:00
5 2019-02-18 12:31:00 2019-02-18 13:12:00
6 2019-02-18 13:12:00 2019-02-18 13:40:00

cut(df$CO2.ppm., exptList$value) gives invalid specification of breaks
```

I think my problem lies in that the exptList shows character instead of dateTime. How can I separate these outs into a column vector?

**EDIT: Some example data.**

Example

```
someDates<-seq(ISOdate(2019,2,7), by = "day", length.out = 12)

cut(someDates,c("2019-02-08 12:00:00 GMT","2019-02-13 12:00:00 GMT"))
Error in cut.POSIXt(someDates, c("2019-02-08 12:00:00 GMT", "2019-02-13 12:00:00 GMT")) : 
  invalid specification of 'breaks'
```

Comment: You can convert it to `datetime` class

Comment: I'm trying: exptList$breaks<-as.POSIXct(value,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") but gives only the last time. I wonder why?